# SQL Server DROP Role

Tags: sql-server-2012, role

I have the following in my post deployment script in Visual Studio 2013:

```
-- Drop existing role and create again to be up to date
DROP ROLE payments_data_access_role
GO

CREATE ROLE payments_data_access_role
GO
```

However when I publish the database from VS, I get the error that the role 'payments_data_access_role' does not exist.

How can I rewrite this so that if the role exists, drop the role and then redefine the role?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:** I tried the following and it worked:

```
IF IS_ROLEMEMBER ('payments_data_access_role') IS NOT NULL
    DROP ROLE payments_data_access_role

CREATE ROLE payments_data_access_role
GO
```

Is this the correct approach? Could you provide your views on this? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IS_ROLEMEMBER` would work like you're using it.

For a deployment, I would just wrap it in a try/catch:

```
BEGIN TRY
    PRINT 'Trying to drop role paymens_data_access_role...';
    DROP ROLE payments_data_access_role;
    Print 'Role payments_data_access_role dropped.';
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Role payments_data_access_role does not exist, not dropping...';
END CATCH;

CREATE ROLE payments_data_access_role;
```

That way you get feedback in your deployment log and the error does not stop execution.  It's also a little more apparent what the intention is compared to  using a function that checks to see if a user belongs to a role.  Might make it easier for you out in the future when you have to come back to this code after a while, or for the next person who's deciphering your code.

Comment: Looks very nice from my point of view. I agree with all you said. Thank you for your help.